# WP AJAX, ajax_url constant is not defined error

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Despite I copied + pasted the WP documentation example for wp_localize_script, so I can use constant ajax_url inside,
$.ajax function as argument, I keep receiving "ajax_url is not defined" error.Here is the code inside functions.php:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
function my_enqueue($hook) {
    if( 'index.php' != $hook ) {
        // Only applies to dashboard panel
        return;
    }
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', plugins_url( '/js/myScript.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );

    // in JavaScript, object properties are accessed as ajax_object.ajax_url, ajax_object.we_value
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object',
                        array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'we_value' => 1234 ) );
}
```

Why ?

Answer (score 0):

It's worth pointing out that in your example, the script is only being localized when accessed via the admin panel. If you'd like to instead access the ajax function from the front end of your site, you'll need to change the first line to this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

You would also then have to remove the first 'if' statement in your function as well.

It's tough to say this is the solution without seeing your code that is trying to call the ajax function, but this is my best guess based off what you've shown us!

Comment: No, has not been solved. would you like to see more code, and if so, in what other files ?

Comment: I have solved the problem. the action hook didn't occur, because wp_head() command was missing inside <head></head>